# Angular 6 + Spring Boot. Некорректная загрузка приложения

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular, angular-cli, angular6

Всем доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня могла возникнуть следующая проблема:
После того, как было собрано и запущено приложение, окно в браузере выводит странный контент. Кроме этого, в исходниках видно, что отсутствуют скомпилированные скрипты.

[image: страница]

Однако, если прописать в адресной строке `.../index.html` - приложение прогружается и начинает работать.

[image: страница]

И все же, если обновить страницу браузера - в таком случае опять повторится ситуация, как на рисунке выше (если url был вида `url/<application_context>/`) или ошибка Whitelabel Error Page (если url был вида `url/<application_context>/child/anotherChild...`)

Я в некотором замешательстве, что может вызвать такие проблемы, поэтому даже не знаю, какие исходники следует приложить, чтобы помочь в решении. Вот некоторые из них:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "asterisk-prime-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "..": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build-dev": "ng build --aot --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk",
    "extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src/app --output ./src/assets/i18n/*.json --clean --sort --format namespaced-json --marker _",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.7",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^2.3.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/sockjs-client": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/stompjs": "^2.3.4",
    "@types/yargs": "^12.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.1.5",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "yargs": "^12.0.5"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "/",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "asterisk-prime-ui": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "less"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../../../asterisk-prime/src/main/resources/static/asterisk-prime-ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "asterisk-prime-ui-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "asterisk-prime-ui:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "asterisk-prime-ui",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href=".">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>AsteriskPrimeUI</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Frontend часть собирается и выкладывается в static-ресурсы spring-boot приложения (см. `"outputPath": "../../../../asterisk-prime/src/main/resources/static/asterisk-prime-ui"`). Далее все это собирается в war-архив.

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Value("#{'${web.mvc.crossOrigins}'.split(',')}")
    private String[] crossOrigins;

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/public/",
            "classpath:/static/asterisk-prime-ui/"
    };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**"))
        {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
        }

        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**"))
        {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins(crossOrigins)
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver urlViewResolver()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Всем заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение потребовало внести изменения и в backend (Spring Boot), и в frontend (Angular 6).

### 1. Backend

В части Spring Boot все изменения коснулись корректирования настроек WebMvc. В частности, изменил ViewResolver:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

А так же добавил "переброс" на `index.html` при мапинге `/` (как выяснилось, это, в своем роде, стандартный механизм при использовании одностраничного приложения (с использованием Angular, React или подобных им):

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
}
```

Окончательный вид конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.prime.asterisk.web.controller"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Value("#{'${web.mvc.crossOrigins}'.split(',')}")
    private String[] crossOrigins;

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/public/",
            "classpath:/static/asterisk-prime-ui/"
    };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**"))
        {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins(crossOrigins)
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

### 2. Frontend

В части UI так же необходимо было внести свои правки.

В первую очередь, добавить атрибуты `base-href` и `deploy-url` для скриптов сборки. В моем случае использован шаблон: `/<application-context>/`, где `<application-context>` - `asterisk-prime`. В целом, в большинстве случаев достаточно было бы поставить атрибут `base-href`, однако в моем случае этого было мало, т.к. `assets` проекта не использовали `base-href` в качестве префикса src-атрибута. Возможно есть другое решение, однако в моем случае достаточно было добавить атрибут `deploy-url`. Окончательный вид скриптов:

```
...
"build-prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /asterisk-prime/ --deploy-url /asterisk-prime/",
...
"build-dev": "ng build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href /asterisk-prime/ --deploy-url /asterisk-prime/",
...
```

Далее не менее важным действием было изменить стратегию роутинга приложения. А именно, активировать параметр `useHash=true` в соответствующем модуле:

```
...
RouterModule.forRoot(AppConfigRoutesFactory.getRoutes(), {useHash: true})
...
```

P.S.: `AppConfigRoutesFactory` - класс со статическим методом отдачи Routes (просто передайте туда свои Routes)

Окончательный вид `AppRoutesModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppConfigRoutesFactory.getRoutes(),
      {
        useHash: true,
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
      })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Далее просто необходимо импортировать этот модуль в ваш AppModule. Использовать hash в роутинге следует, если при обновлении страницы выходит ошибка Whitelabel Error Page.

Всем большое спасибо за всю оказанную помощь, за комментарии и попытки хотя-бы помочь в направлении поиска проблемы.

Comment: Да не за что, всегда рад помочь!

Comment: Не нужно здесь язвить! Правильно поставленный вопрос - это половина ответа. То, что вы сделали кучу скринов и показали зачем-то `index.html, angular.json, package.json, tsconfig.json` вообще не имеют отношения ни к ответу, ни к вопросу

Comment: Тем не менее я сразу указал в вопросе, что, к сожалению, был в некотором замешательстве и не мог предположить, какие исходники можно было бы приложить, чтобы помочь с ответом.

Comment: ```index.html``` я приложил затем, чтобы было видно ,что я там ничего лишнего не прописал (однако все же там был прописан атрибут ```<base href=".">```, что не является критичным, но тем не менее, возможно, понадобится для поиска возможной проблемы). ```angular.json``` и ```tsconfig.json``` так же мог помочь в поиске проблемы, т.к. там зачастую указаны атрибуты сборки. А ```package.json``` был необходим, т.к. в нем были ошибки скриптов сборки. Конечно я могу ошибаться, но в любом случае я сразу пояснил, что сбит с толку и прикладываю ту информацию, которую посчитал нужным.